# Payment is not Gathered

Tags: magento-1.8, payment, payment-gateway, paypal-payments-pro

I am working on a Magento site. Version of the site is 1.8.1.0. I configured Payment Method like below.

[image]

But Payment is not gathered after order. Why it is happening ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you explain more. gathered means not capture correctly. What's your payment action?

Comment: @SohelRana vai, Assalamu Alaikum. Yes, Payment is not gathered in Store Owners Account.

Comment: Check authentication parameter like api signature, username, password etc.